# What is the best way to handle dependent observable subscription in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have an observable which emits some id and i have to make an another subscription which uses the emitted ids. What is the best way to handle this subscription. I know a solution like subscribing the second observable inside the the first observable subscription. Like below -

```
observable1$.subsctipe(id=>{ 
   this.store.pipe(select(some_selector, id)).subscribe(value=>{
      //some business
   })
})
```

Is this solution has any bad effect like memory leaks? And is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad effect of this thing is that you have two subscriptions to keep track of. You have to unsubscribe both to clean up.

```
observable1$.pipe(mergeMap(id => 
   this.store.pipe(select(some_selector, id))
).subscribe(value => {
   //some business
})
```

Better do it like this. Then you have only one subscription to release if the component destroys. This is not the case with your current implementation.

I also assume that you dont want to keep listening to your store with the old `id` if `observable1$` has already emittet a new `id`. If thats the case, you can replace `mergeMap` with `switchMap`. Btw `flatMap` is an alias for `mergeMap`.